# enp3s0 link DOWN after playing Quake Champions

Tags: networking, internet, games

Playing Quake Champions on steamplay. A few minutes into the game, my PC gets disconnected from my router. Things get back to normal a few minutes after, but sometimes I have to restart the PC.

`ip addr`'s output after I get the problem:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:cb:8a:6f:f7:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:22:81:b8:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker_gwbridge: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:30:ef:fc:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`journalctl`'s output when searching for anything containing enp3s0:

```
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931960.4543] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931960.4561] device (enp3s0): DHCPv4 lease renewal requested
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931960.4900] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1073
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931960.4901] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931960.4904] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931960.5007] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 30809
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30809]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x5182160d)
Aug 09 03:12:40 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30809]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x5182160d)
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931963.8936] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931963.8936] device (enp3s0): DHCPv4 lease renewal requested
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931963.9259] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 30809
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931963.9259] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931963.9263] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931963.9278] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 30817
Aug 09 03:12:43 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30817]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xa8466a1)
Aug 09 03:12:44 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down
Aug 09 03:12:46 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30817]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xa8466a1)
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931969.3100] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931969.3100] device (enp3s0): DHCPv4 lease renewal requested
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931969.3741] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 30817
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931969.3744] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931969.3750] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931969.3763] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 30831
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30831]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1fdbff93)
Aug 09 03:12:49 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down
Aug 09 03:12:52 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30831]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1fdbff93)
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931973.2037] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931973.2038] device (enp3s0): DHCPv4 lease renewal requested
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931973.2198] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 30831
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931973.2198] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931973.2201] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931973.2212] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 30840
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30840]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x74861667)
Aug 09 03:12:53 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down
Aug 09 03:12:56 sulaiman-pc dhclient[30840]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x74861667)
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931980.2345] device (enp3s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931980.3013] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 30840
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596931980.3014] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.107.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Interface enp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Withdrawing address record for fd94:e94:2f20:1:2dae:dbe8:6db0:cfbf on enp3s0.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Withdrawing address record for fd94:e94:2f20:1:2d39:cc12:4a9b:e33e on enp3s0.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fd94:e94:2f20:1:2d39:cc12:4a9b:e33e.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Interface enp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc nm-dispatcher[30948]: req:2 'down' [enp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 09 03:13:00 sulaiman-pc nm-dispatcher[30948]: req:2 'down' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6222] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6226] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 10 Mbps Full
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6341] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Home' (be62c1f6-98f5-324a-ac40-0c2a4ed6d3f7)
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6342] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6345] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6353] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6356] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932000.6370] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 31416
Aug 09 03:13:20 sulaiman-pc dhclient[31416]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x415a77e1)
Aug 09 03:13:22 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78.
Aug 09 03:13:22 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:13:22 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Registering new address record for fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78 on enp3s0.*.
Aug 09 03:13:22 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down
Aug 09 03:13:23 sulaiman-pc dhclient[31416]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x415a77e1)
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc dhclient[31416]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x415a77e1)
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932008.6155] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932008.6476] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 31416
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932008.6476] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78 on enp3s0.
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78.
Aug 09 03:13:28 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Interface enp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1043] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 10 Mbps Full
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1046] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1066] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Home' (be62c1f6-98f5-324a-ac40-0c2a4ed6d3f7)
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1068] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1073] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1077] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1079] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932181.1103] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 31704
Aug 09 03:16:21 sulaiman-pc dhclient[31704]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4beeaf1f)
Aug 09 03:16:22 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78.
Aug 09 03:16:22 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:16:22 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Registering new address record for fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78 on enp3s0.*.
Aug 09 03:16:23 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down
Aug 09 03:16:24 sulaiman-pc dhclient[31704]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4beeaf1f)
Aug 09 03:16:27 sulaiman-pc dhclient[31704]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4beeaf1f)
Aug 09 03:16:29 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932189.4141] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:16:29 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932189.4461] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 31704
Aug 09 03:16:29 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[940]: <info>  [1596932189.4461] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 09 03:16:29 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78 on enp3s0.
Aug 09 03:16:29 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78.
Aug 09 03:16:29 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[950]: Interface enp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:17:33 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
Aug 09 03:17:36 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932256.4201] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0, iface: enp3s0)
Aug 09 03:17:36 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932256.4202] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0, iface: enp3s0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug 09 03:17:36 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932256.5934] manager: (enp3s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Aug 09 03:17:36 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932256.5940] device (enp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 09 03:17:36 sulaiman-pc kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Aug 09 03:17:36 sulaiman-pc kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1576] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1578] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1588] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Home' (be62c1f6-98f5-324a-ac40-0c2a4ed6d3f7)
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1589] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1592] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1595] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc kernel: alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1783] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932265.1808] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 2611
Aug 09 03:17:45 sulaiman-pc dhclient[2611]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6cf3a48b)
Aug 09 03:17:46 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78.
Aug 09 03:17:46 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:17:46 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Registering new address record for fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78 on enp3s0.*.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc dhclient[2611]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6cf3a48b)
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   address 192.168.1.107
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   lease time 86400
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '62.215.6.51'
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '62.215.6.52'
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3684] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.107.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.107 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3691] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3696] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.3697] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.4257] policy: set 'Home' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1596932268.4260] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc nm-dispatcher[1063]: req:4 'up' [enp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc nm-dispatcher[1063]: req:4 'up' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fd94:e94:2f20:1:401a:27c8:8cd7:833d.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Registering new address record for fd94:e94:2f20:1:401a:27c8:8cd7:833d on enp3s0.*.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1c11:786e:9f29:bf78 on enp3s0.
Aug 09 03:17:48 sulaiman-pc avahi-daemon[944]: Registering new address record for fd94:e94:2f20:1:2d39:cc12:4a9b:e33e on enp3s0.*.
```

System information:

```
OS: KDE neon 5.19
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-112-generic
DE: KDE 5.72.0 / Plasma 5.19.4
WM: KWin
```

Comment: What is the question specifically?

Comment: How do I solve this problem? @user1794469

Comment: could even be the router resetting for whatever reason. You could insert a switch between the router and the computer. If you still get a Link Down, it's on the computer's side (whatever it is), if not, but the game still hangs and router's link gets down according to the switch's led, it's on the router's side.